# Uploading Media Via iOS5/6

Tags: ios, media, libraries, uploading

Is it possible (and if so, how) to allow a user within an iOS5/6 application to upload audio, video, text, and image based files from within the standard iOS application libraries (such as Music, Photos, Videos, etc.) and/or third-party applications libraries (such as Dropbox, Google Drive, iCloud, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if the third party has an API or SDK that allows access from an iOS application. Apple provides APIs for accessing music, photos, and documents. If you consult the documentation provided by the software providers, they should all have examples of how gaining access to the files can be accomplished. The uploading of the files to wherever they are going would be your application's responsibility.